# How to return JSON "true" in Python

Tags: python, json

I have a simple python code that returns a JSON object with one boolean fields and two others. The goal is to get the following response

```
{
    "prop": "foo",
    "name": "bar",
    "isSomething": true
}
```

I need a valid JSON `true`, but the python response gives me a JSON string `"true"`.

```
{
    "prop": "foo",
    "name": "bar",
    "isSomething": "true"
}
```

My Python code is:

```
import json
x = { 
        'prop' : 'foo',
        'name': 'bar',
        'isSomething': json.dumps(True)
    }  
return x
```

I am executing this code using Python 3.7.

Comment: Your function does not return a JSON object, it returns a Python dictionary. For the key `'isSomething'` you've put the a `str` object representing the JSON boolean true value, so of course, that will be a string. You probably just want to put `True` and whatever handle the serialization to JSON downstream will handle that correctly.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You're right, please add this as an answer so I can accept, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should `json.dumps` the entire `x` object:

```
import json
x = { 
        'prop' : 'foo',
        'name': 'bar',
        'isSomething': True
    }  
return json.dumps(x)
```

Comment: This returns `"{\"prop\": \"foo\", \"name\": \"bar\", \"isSomething\": true}"`

Comment: @hkjhadj1 That's correct (sort of; I would have expected `'{"prop": "foo", "name": "bar", "isSomething": true}'`). Up to representation , `'"foo"'` and `"\"foo\""` are equivalent.

Comment: @hkjhadj1: It sounds like you may be applying *yet another* layer of JSON serialization after this, in which case you shouldn't call any `json` functions at all here, and the later layer will handle it.

Comment: No it doesn't. It returns `{"prop": "foo", "name": "bar", "isSomething": true}`. Which is valid JSON. I just checked. If your code somewhere adds another layer, then this can be different, but as you did not show that code, this is all I can do now ;-).